# What is the use of /proc/PID/cpuset?

Tags: proc

In `/proc` filesystem, what is the use of `/proc/<pid>/cpuset`?

I tried to open this file in each of the process id directories inside the `/proc` folder:

```
$ cat /proc/2882/cpuset
/
```

Can some one help me to understand what is the use of this file?

Answer (score 3):

In short:

> cpuset - confine processes to processor and memory node subsets

In addition to the above pseudo-files in each directory below `/dev/cpuset`, each process has a pseudo-file, `/proc/<pid>/cpuset`, that displays the path of the process's `cpuset` directory relative to the root of the cpuset file system.

Also the `/proc/<pid>/status` file for each process has four added lines, displaying the process's Cpus_allowed (on which CPUs it may be scheduled) and Mems_allowed (on which memory nodes it may obtain memory), in the two formats Mask Format and List Format as shown in the following example:

```
Cpus_allowed:   ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff
Cpus_allowed_list:     0-127
Mems_allowed:   ffffffff,ffffffff
Mems_allowed_list:     0-63
```

The "allowed" fields were added in Linux 2.6.24; the "allowed_list" fields were added in Linux 2.6.26.

From [man 7 cpuset](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/cpuset.7.html).